# Can i change value of Adjacency Matrix on Python Programming?

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have problem with my code, i cannot print or change value of Adjacency matrix, can you help me sir?
i have code like this

```
for i in range(len(A.todense())):
    for j in A[i].todense()*1:
        print(j)
```

and the output is

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
[[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]]
[[1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

and want to change zero to one, or one to zero, but i cannot print or change with A.todense()[i][j]. Can you help me to change the value of adjacency matrix? Thanks you

[top up saldo paypal](https://jualsaldo.com)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can't change value in Adjancency matrix, so that you have to convert to numpy or other array type that can change value.

One Solution Below

```
A = np.array(A.data)
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        if A[i][j] == 0:
            A[i][j] = 1
        else:
            A[i][j] = 0
```

That will change values and then convert to Adjancency matrix.

Comment: If the array contained bools instead of  ints, a simple `~` or `numpy.logical_not()` would suffice.